# Check extended parameters for R package

Tags: r, package, documentation

When I use R package and use "?function" to search for helpful information or documentation, I usually find there is an incomplete parameter list. There are many information omitted in "...". Even when I download the brochure for package documentation, there are many parameters I can't find descriptions. Do we need to download the package source code to dig into the usage of these omitted parameters? What's a good way to master R packages when you have passed entry level?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question so if you could give an example that would be great. Often the `...` arguments are passed to some other function within the function (which is usually noted but sometimes isn't) so the best way to know what can be specified there is to look at the documentation for that function

Comment: For example, in glmnet r package, if I check cv.glmnet function, there are some parameters omitted in ... The documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf in this link also omitted the parameters. I find online material that uses parameter like lower.limits or upper.limits in cv.glmnet function call. But I can't find it in documentation or helper information.

Comment: Another example will be more difficult to find. When I call a dataframe like df[, -1, drop = False], this function has parameter like drop = False, which prevents the dataframe being degraded to a vector when the dataframe only has one column. But I can't find any documentation for this.

Comment: Is looking at the source code the only way to learn this?

Comment: The documentation clearly says what to pass to `...` in `cv.glmnet`. You can pass it arguments of the `glmnet` function. In the documentation of `glmnet` you can see that it has arguments like `lower.limits`. You don't need to look at source code. You need to read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Roland! For the documentation "drop = False" in for df[, -1, drop = False], is there also documentation to check this?

Comment: Yes you're right it is harder to find but it is there you just need to know what to look for. In this case the brackets are documented under Extract in the base library so if you type `?Extract` you can find it or it is also here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html

Comment: @andrewb or just `help("[")`